# Putting two related questions under one vs. creating two separate questions for related topics

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

So I just posted a question and few minutes later I thought of another question that is related to the original one. So what should we do in such circumstances; is it better to keep the two questions under one since they are highly related? Or should we break them up in two to keep questions short and make it easier for other users to answer each question?

Here is my situation for example:
Carey Price of MTL Canadiens and Henrik Lundqvist of NY Rangers are facing in the NHL playoffs. They have both won Olympic gold medal, also they met in the Olympics final this year.
This is the question I posted:"How many times two Olympics gold medal winner goalies faced in the NHL playoffs"
This is the second question that I have now:"How many times goalies who met in the Olympics gold medal game faced in the NHL playoffs in the same year"
As you can see these two question are with no doubt very related. Which approach is the best here? Putting them together, or keeping them separated?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/334/is-it-okay-to-ask-multiple-questions-of-the-same-topic-in-a-single-question?rq=1